# MySQL Left pad and update

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to left pad a field and then save the result as a new account number. I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about this and am having trouble finding solutions.

So far I pass the necessary information from C# into a stored procedure.

```
using (var connectionCommand = new SqlCommand("updateNumbers", conn) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure}) 

        //add input parameters
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@proc_dateStart", startDate));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@proc_dateEnd", endDate));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@proc_accountNumber", _accountNumber));
```

Currently I think replicate is the best way to go about this. However I'm having trouble planning for variation in user input. This needs to support padding between 2 to 6 digits. So an example would be:

Input: 1234
Output: 001234 or 0000001234

I can easily enough account for the 0 being another number, but it seems like replicate relies on a fixed length - field length.

```
    UPDATE [StatementItem] 
SET Account = replicate(@proc_digit, 10 - len(Account) + cast(Account as varchar) as newAccountNumber)
WHERE Account = accountNumber 
AND TransactionDate BETWEEN proc_dateStart AND proc_dateEnd;
```

Any suggestions? There must be a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I always do:

```
RIGHT(REPLICATE('<padchar>', <length>) + [<field>], <length>)
```

where

- `<padchar>` is the padding character (e.g. `0`)
- `<length>` is the final/maximum length of the string (e.g. `10`)
- `<field>` is the existing field that needs padding (e.g. `Account`)

The end effect is that no matter what your input length, it will always result in a string of length `10`.

For example, for account '1234' the process looks like:

```
'1234'
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + '1234', 10)
RIGHT('0000000000' + '1234', 10)
RIGHT('00000000001234', 10)
'0000001234'
```

Or for '987654':

```
'987654'
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + '987654', 10)
RIGHT('0000000000' + '987654', 10)
RIGHT('0000000000987654', 10)
'0000987654'
```